# Do the maxima of the supernovae redshift distribution correspond to generation of stars dying?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy, stars, supernova

Within the Big Bang model, matter appears then coalesces to form stars that in turn die; some of them going boom in a supernova. Assuming the Universe is isotropic, one should observe maxima in the time-(or redshift) distribution of supernova, each maximum corresponding to a generation of stars dying. Is this the case?

If yes, how many generations of stars have happened since the Big Bang, and if not, is there an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't as simple as that. Stars are born with a distribution of masses and are born continuously in time. There are no discrete "generations" of star formation, even within a single galaxy, let alone the entire universe.

However, it is the case that the star formation rate of the entire universe peaked in the past, and this would have marked the most intense epoch of (core-collapse) supernovae and a maximum in the enrichment rate for chemical elements produced in massive stars and disseminated by supernovae (e.g. oxygen, neon, magnesium).

The graph below shows a typical example of an estimate of the star forming rate of the universe as a function of redshift (and hence its age, from http://firstgalaxies.org/explore.html ). As you can see, the rate peaked about 10 billion years ago, and because massive stars have very short lives, the peak in the supernova rate would have been at the same time.

[image: SFR of the universe]

Comment: I have just realized the rate of death must be equal to the rate of birth, so you have answered my question...